# Calorie Multiplier

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to program a calculator that works out how many calories you have burnt based on their average speed. Currently I cannot get the Calories burnt correct.

```
Dim Distance As Double
    Dim Duration As Double
    Dim Speed As Long
    Dim Caloriesburnt As Integer
    Dim Multiplier As Integer

    Distance = nupDistance.Value
    Duration = nupDuration.Value

    Speed = Distance / Duration
    txtAverageSpeed.Text = Speed


    If txtAverageSpeed.Text <= 5 Then
        Multiplier = 472

    ElseIf 5 < txtAverageSpeed.Text <= 6 Then
        Multiplier = 590

    ElseIf 6 < txtAverageSpeed.Text <= 7 Then
        Multiplier = 679

    ElseIf 7 < txtAverageSpeed.Text <= 8 Then
        Multiplier = 797

    ElseIf 8 < txtAverageSpeed.text <= 9 Then
        Multiplier = 885

    Else
        Multiplier = 994

    End If
    Caloriesburnt = Multiplier * Duration
    txtCaloriesBurnt.Text = Caloriesburnt
```

Comment: First, turn on Option Strict.  `If txtAverageSpeed.Text <= 5` is comparing text/string to a number. Then look up the syntax for `Else`.  `ElseIf 8 < txtAverageSpeed.text <= 9` needs to use AND for 2 comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

You already got a variable speed, don't use the textbox. By turning option strict on you will notice the error. Comparing string with numbers with not a good idea.

You should read on how to properly use if statment in VB. Doing  5 < x <= 6 will not do what you expect, you'll have to do x < 5 and x <= 6. By having the else, you can omit the first check.

```
If Speed <= 5 Then
    Multiplier = 472
ElseIf Speed <= 6 Then
    Multiplier = 590
ElseIf Speed <= 7 Then
    Multiplier = 679
ElseIf Speed <= 8 Then
    Multiplier = 797
ElseIf Speed <= 9 Then
    Multiplier = 885
Else
    Multiplier = 994
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "speed" variable is of type `long` which means it's **integral**.  How can you have a value that is > 5 and < 6 then?  It will simply be 6!

This could also be done with a `Select Case` statement:

```
Select Case speed
    Case Is <= 5
        Multiplier = 472
    Case 6
        Multiplier = 590
    Case 7
        Multiplier = 679
    Case 8
        Multiplier = 797
    Case 9
        Multiplier = 885
    Case Else
        Multiplier = 994
End Select
```